# how to display the right value?

Tags: php, html, sql

Im trying to show the respective comments to the respective question ID but all the comments are shown in every post.
actually the value of qusetion ID is not going to the desired table where it suppose to be and that table

```html
name: add_topic.php

<body>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$con)
{
die("could not connect to the server".mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($con,'forum');


// Get value of id that sent from hidden field 
$id=$_POST['id'];

// Find highest answer number. 
$q="SELECT MAX(a_id) AS Maxa_id FROM forum_ans WHERE que_id='$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$q);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// add + 1 to highest answer number and keep it in variable name "$Max_id". if there no answer yet set it = 1 
if ($row) {
$Max_id = $row['Maxa_id']+1;
}
else {
$Max_id = 1;
}

// get values that sent from form 

$a_name=$_POST['a_name'];
$a_email=$_POST['a_email'];
$a_ans=$_POST['a_ans']; 

$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time

// Insert answer 
$q2="INSERT INTO forum_ans(que_id, a_id, a_name, a_email, a_ans, a_datetime)VALUES('$id', '$Max_id', '$a_name', '$a_email', '$a_ans', '$datetime')";
$result2=mysqli_query($con,$q2);

if($result2){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href='view_topic.php?id=".$id."'>View your answer</a>";

// If added new answer, add value +1 in reply column 

$q3="UPDATE forum_que SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysqli_query($con,$q3);
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
```

block that named as que_id is showing the value of 0 (as i have set 0 as its default value) and that is the main reason of it but im not able to solve this problem. plz help...

```html
  name: view_topic.php


<body>
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$con)
{
die("could not connect to the server".mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($con,'forum');



// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$q="SELECT * FROM forum_que WHERE id='$id'";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$q);

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong><?php echo $row['topic']; ?></strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $row['detail']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>By :</strong> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> <strong>Email : </strong><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/time : </strong><?php echo $row['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<BR>

<?php

// Switch to table "forum_answer"
$q2="SELECT * FROM forum_ans WHERE que_id='$id'";
$result2=mysqli_query($con,$q2);
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $row2['a_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $row2['a_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $row2['a_email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $row2['a_ans']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $row2['a_datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table><br>
 
<?php
}

$q3="SELECT view FROM forum_que WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysqli_query($con,$q3);
$row3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
$view=$row3['view'];
 
// if have no counter value set counter = 1
if(empty($view)){
$view=1;
$q4="INSERT INTO forum_que(view) VALUES('$view') WHERE id='$id'";
$result4=mysqli_query($con,$q4);
}
 
// count more value
$addview=$view+1;
$q5="update forum_que set view='$addview' WHERE id='$id'";
$result5=mysqli_query($con,$q5);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<BR>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_ans.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="18%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="3%">:</td>
<td width="79%"><input name="a_name" type="text" id="a_name" size="45"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="a_email" type="text" id="a_email" size="45"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="a_ans" cols="45" rows="3" id="a_ans"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

```html
name: add_topic.php

<body>

<?php



// get data that sent from form 
$topic=$_REQUEST['topic'];
$detail=$_REQUEST['detail'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];

$datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); //create date time

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$con)
{
die("could not connect to the server".mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($con,'forum');


$q="INSERT INTO`forum`.`forum_que`(topic, detail, name, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic', '$detail', '$name', '$email', '$datetime')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$q))
{
echo '<script>alert("Data Inserted Now redirecting to login page");</script>';
header('location:main_forum.php');
}
else
{
echo "error inserting record" . mysqli_error($con,$query);
echo '<script>alert("Error while inserting data");</script>';
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `add_topic.php` should one be `add_ans.php`
I don't see any exact problems with this code are you sure that the `$id` is being used correctly in the hidden field of your form?
Possibly try doing a `print_r($_POST);` on the `add_ans.php` page to see what data is actually being passed by the form